# How to label a tenth of a second properly in a graph?

Tags: graphing-functions, fractions

I'm making a graph for a science class, and the x-axis represents every tenth of a second. What's the best way of labeling that axis other than "time (one tenth of a second)", or is that the best way?

Comment: $\frac{1}{10} $ second = $ 10^2 $ millisecond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestions are
     1. time( $10^{-1} s $ )
     2. t($10^{-1} s $ ) 
     3. t/$10^{1} s^{-1} $ 
but what i think is as long as it express the basic idea of that axis to anyone who reads ur graph it will be fine